# Android quick alarm

Tags: android, alarm

I have a little problem with taking a quick alarm.

The alarm works fine if I set the alarm time before normal "quick alarm". How do I set the alarm for example 8:00 pm, quick alarm for 7:55 pm this works differently does not turn on

```
private void showQuickAlarmDialog() {
    View layout = mFactory.inflate(R.layout.quick_alarm_dialog, null);
    final TextView text1 = (TextView) layout
            .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    final SeekBar slider = (SeekBar) layout
            .findViewById(android.R.id.input);
    int last_snooze = mPrefs.getInt(PREF_LAST_QUICK_ALARM, 0);
    slider.setMax(59);
    slider.setProgress(last_snooze);
    text1.setText(AlarmClock.this.getString(R.string.minutes,
            String.valueOf(last_snooze + 1)));
    slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek, int value,
                boolean fromTouch) {
            text1.setText(AlarmClock.this.getString(R.string.minutes,
                    String.valueOf(value + 1)));
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
        }
    });

    AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.quick_alarm)
            .setView(layout)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                            int snooze_min = slider.getProgress() + 1;
                            long snoozeTarget = System.currentTimeMillis()+ 1000 * 60 * snooze_min;
                            Alarms.calculateNextAlert(AlarmClock.this).getAlert();
                        //if (nextAlarm > snoozeTarget) {
                                 //alarm will fire before snooze will...
                        //}
                            //else {
                                Alarms.saveSnoozeAlert(
                                        AlarmClock.this,0,snoozeTarget,AlarmClock.this.getString(R.string.quick_alarm));

                                Alarms.setNextAlert(AlarmClock.this);
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        AlarmClock.this,
                                        getString(
                                                R.string.alarm_alert_snooze_set,
                                                snooze_min),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                updateSnoozeVisibility();
                                mPrefs.edit()
                                        .putInt(PREF_LAST_QUICK_ALARM,
                                                snooze_min - 1).commit();
                        //  }
                        }
                    }).show();
}

private void updateSnoozeVisibility() {
    long next_snooze = mPrefs.getLong(Alarms.PREF_SNOOZE_TIME, 0);
    View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.snooze_message);
    if (next_snooze != 0) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snooze_message_text);
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTimeInMillis(next_snooze);
        String snooze_time = Alarms.formatTime(AlarmClock.this, c);
        tv.setText(getString(R.string.snooze_message_text, snooze_time));

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Alarms.disableSnoozeAlert(AlarmClock.this);
                Toast.makeText(AlarmClock.this,
                        getString(R.string.snooze_dismissed),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Alarms.setNextAlert(AlarmClock.this);
            }
        });
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void updateEmptyVisibility() {
    View v = findViewById(R.id.alarms_list_empty);
    if (v != null)
        v.setVisibility(mAlarmsList.getAdapter().getCount() < 1 ? View.VISIBLE
                : View.GONE);
}
```

In one sentence. I can't turn on quick alarm if the normal alarm is set at a later time.

Comment: What's the difference between quick and normal alarm?

Comment: Normal work like a normal alarm clock. Quick alarm works so that you set, for example, 10 minutes and have a break. It is faster than the alarm set